# Remainder term for Maclaurin's $\sin x$ expansion

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

We know that for the Maclaurin's series $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{ f^{k}(0) }{(n+1)!}x^{k}$$ the remainder term is given by the following formula:
$$R_{n} = \frac{\left | f^{(n+1)}(z) \right |x^{n+1} }{(n+1)!}$$

I want to calculate $\sin x$ using Maclaurin's expansion for $$\sin x = \sum^w_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} x^{2k+1} $$

and then i want to calculate the remainder term using $w$. Now considering that $n=2w +1$, I think that the remainder term should look like this: 
$$R_{w} = \frac{\left | f^{(2w+1+1)}(z) \right |x^{2w+1+1} }{(2w+1+1)!}$$ where $f(x) = \sin x$.

Would this formula for the remainder term be correct?

Comment: Might you have meant $(n+1)!$ where you wrote $(n+1!)$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remainder term after the term of degree $2w+1$ in the power series expansion of $f$ is $$R_w= f^{(2w+2)}(z)x^{2w+2}/(2w+2)!$$ for some $z$ between $0$ and $x$ when $x\ne 0\;$ (or $z=0$ when $x=0.)\;$ Now when $f=\sin$ we have  $f^{(2w+2)}(z)=(-1)^w\sin z.$ We can re-write $R_w$ by noting that $\sin z= z(1-a)=x(1-b)(1-c)=x(1-d)$ where $a,b,c\in (0,1)$, so that $$R_w=(-1)^wx^{2w+3}(1-c)/(2w+2)! \quad \text {with }\;  c\in (0,1).$$ Of course, $c$ depends on $x$ and $w$. When $w$ is sufficiently large, the value of $(1-c)(2w+3)$ is approximately $1$.

Comment: I think it's $(-1)^{w+1}sinz$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You obtain a greater precision if you take into account the expansion of $\sin x$  at order $2w+1$ is *ipso facto* an expansion at order $2w+2$.

Comment: Typo for $2w+2$?

Comment: @Bernard Could you be a little clearer on that please?

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: Yes! Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @Alice1nw0: As you know the expansion for $\sin x $ has no term of even degree. However, you may apply Lagrange's formula for the remainder at order $2w+2$, obtaining a remainder in $x^{2k+3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another hint:
The derivatives cycle through
$\pm\sin(z)$
and
$\pm\cos(z)$.

Also note that,
if 
$a_w
=\frac{x^{2w+1+1} }{(2w+1+1)!}
=\frac{x^{2w+2} }{(2w+2)!}
$,
then
$\frac{a_w}{a_{w-1}}
=\frac{\frac{x^{2w+2} }{(2w+2)!}}{\frac{x^{2w} }{(2w)!}}
=\frac{x^2}{2w(2w+1)}
$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way without Taylor remainder term:

The sine and cosine series are alternating. By the Leibniz test and its error estimate, the error is always smaller than the last term (if the last term is smaller than the next-to-last term), i.e., for $x>0$ one has the inclusion
$$
x-\frac{x^3}6\pm …- \frac{x^{4m-1}}{(4m-1)!}\le \sin x\le x-\frac{x^3}6\pm …+ \frac{x^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)!}
$$
for arbitrary $m,n$ and especially for $m=n$ and $m=n+1$ under the condition $x<4n$.